# Getting crash using afnetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Hi i am using old version of afnetwoking get crash report on fabric but not find any solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This type of crash can be due to sending message to an already released object. Check your code for any such venerability.

You may profile your app with leaks instrument to see and leakage. Goto Product->Profile